# Handling HTTP Requests in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, http, get

How do I handle HTTP GET queries in my website like mywebsite.com/Hi%26Hello or mywebsite.com/Dogs%26Cats.

Using plain JavaScript and Github Pages is it possible to respond to GET requests like this and show pages related to the query?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **respond** to GET requests?

No.

HTTP requests are received by an HTTP server.

You can write an HTTP server using JavaScript (commonly with Node.js + Express.js) but Github Pages doesn't support any form of server-side programming.